# how do I strengthen my code for unexpected input?

Tags: python-3.x

```
while True:
    race = int(input('1. Roegadyn\n'
                     '2. Hyur\n'
                     '3. Elezen\n'
                     '4. Mi\'Qote\n'
                     '5. Lalafell\n'
                     'Choose a race: '))
    if (race not in range(1,6)):
        print('\nInvalid Entry.\n')
    else:
        break
```

When I try to break this it's pretty easy, really looking now it's obvious why it's so crappy. Any advice on giving my query structure integrity would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for helping a noob.

Comment: `(race not in range(1,6))` is normally written as the more efficient `1 <= race <= 6` while inverting the two clauses (the main one and the `else` one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your entries into a separate structure and use it for the appropriate values. And check for exceptions.

```
rmap = {n: r for (n, r) in enumerate(['Roegadyn', 'Hyur',…], 1)}

while True:
    for n, r in sorted(rmap.items()):
        print('{}. {}'.format(n, r))
    rval = input('Choose a race: ')
    try:
        rnum = int(rval)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        if rnum in rmap:
            break
    print('Invalid Entry')
```

Comment: +1: Good structure! It is recommended to keep a `try` clause as small as possible (so as to better control and indicate where exceptions come from): I shortened it. I also fixed the `input()`, which failed when the user entered a string. I would personally skip the `rval = …`  step because `rval` is not used more than once, but this is somewhat a matter of taste.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I had missed that part. Going to revert to `input()`.  I also fixed your `iteritems()`, since it does not exist in Python 3.

Comment: Whoops, yeah, missed the method change. Thanks.

Comment: I also created the numbered choice list automatically, as in this case choices are consecutive numbers.

Comment: In this case that is true. But in general it is better to expand for clarity and flexibility.

Comment: @Gov: Something closer to your original approach for checking the range would work too: `rmap` would be `rlist = ['Roegadyn',…]`, and you would have instead `for n, r in enumerate(rlist, 1)`, and `if 1 <= rnum <= len(rlist)`. Since in your case you only have consecutive numerical inputs, this works. Ignacio's solution is in more general and flexible (non consecutive numbers,…). You would keep the general test structure, though (`try`, then `else if`).

Comment: This is great, I knew I should be using a `try` statement but what I came up with still wasn't quite working well. Thanks a ton, this is clearly a technique I can keep with me and use when I'm requesting input.

Thanks again!

Comment: The best way to figure out which exceptions you need to catch is to fire up the REPL and try to cause them. `3>> int('e')`
`Traceback ...` ... `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'`

Comment: Noted, I'll try using that while I work on this (little)program. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to mention a simpler solution:

```
races = ["Roegadyn", "Hyur", "Elezen", "Mi'Qote | Seekers of the Sun", "Lalafell"]

while True:

    print(*("{}. {}".format(*race_info) for race_info in enumerate(races, 1)),
          sep="\n")

    try:
        race = races[int(input('Choose a race: '))-1]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        print('\nInvalid Entry.\n')
    else:
        break
```

The advantage of this solution is that both problems (non-numerical input and index out of range) are treated on the same footing, which makes the code more legible. In particular, there is no need for an explicit check of the numerical input.

Ignacio's solution is fine, but it mixes the "**Look before you leap**" approach (`rnum in rmap`) with the "**Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission**" (`try`). Since both errors are normally quite rare, it is a good idea to put the normal behavior (`break`) in a `try… else` clause.

Side note: There is no need for a `\'` escape in your list of races, since one can use `"…"` quotes, like here. In your original question, you can use string concatenation in the same way: `'Roegadyn' … "Mi'Qote" …`.

PS: In this solution `race` is actually a race and not a race reference number, contrary to the original question. For a numerical `race`, one can do instead `try: race = int(…); races[race] except…` (but this does not look as good).

Comment: I do like this as well... Something I probably should have clarified earlier(I didn't expect this much assistance) is that there are two subraces to each race. So actually my rmap variable has values delineated with `|` for another function I have that reads from a .txt file and prints out stats for the selected race.

`"Mi'Qote | Seekers of the Sun"` is one example so the dictionary worked well in this case though a list would work just as well I think. If you're curious to see what code I have so far I'd be happy to send you the source.

Comment: Yeah, a list would work the same: I updated the answer so as to allow for spaces in the race names.